# How to filter on several columns but modify input for one of them?

Tags: jquery, datatables

My table is local, data is read from an HTML table. I'm trying to use a single external input as filter on all the table, which works perfectly:

```
$('.data-table').DataTable({
  columns: [
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null,
    { orderable: false }
  ]
});

$(document).on('input', 'input.filter', function () {
  var searchTerm = this.value

  $('.data-table').DataTable().search(searchTerm).draw();
});
```

But what I can't do right now is modify `searchTerm` only when applied to the first column. It should compare unmodified to the rest of the table. I tried a custom search function but I don't understand how to skip it if it's not the column where I need the custom function:

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
  var columnVal = data[0]
  var input = $('input.filter').val()

  if (input) {
    // This comparison should only apply on the first column.
    return columnVal == input.slice(1)
  } else {
    return true
  };
});
```

For example, when the user inputs 'K123', searching or filtering against the full table should use 'K123', but I want to match the first column with a sliced input (specifically '123').

[According to the author](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/72690/#Comment_72690) the right approach (without a custom filter) should be like this:

```
var input = $('input.filter').val()

table
  .search( input )
  .column( 0 ).search( input.slice(1) )
  .draw();
```

But I can't make it work :(

Answer (score 1):

data should be an array that hold all the data of the row. You may also want to call splice on it to remove the first one, depends on your need.

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(function(settings, data, dataIndex){      
    var input = $('input.filter').val(), firstColumnVal = "";
    if (input) {
        firstColumnVal = input.slice(1);
    }
    var firstColumnData = data[0];
    if (!input) 
        return true;
    else 
        return firstColumnVal === firstColumnData || data.indexOf(input) > -1;   
});
```

Comment: Yes but I also want to search with the same term on the rest of the table

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.. It sounds like you still want to do a global search? Then why bother to target on the first column at all? Can you provide an example?

Comment: Thanks for trying, I'm not explaining myself like I should. I've added an example to the question.

Comment: Oh, I hadn't thought about doing comparison on that custom function with the rest of the data. This is what your're doing here with `data.indexOf(input) > -1;` right? But what if the match with the rest of the columns is partial? Anyway, great pointers, thanks

Comment: For partial match you can use `data.filter(function(s) {return s.indexOf(input) > -1;}).length > 0`